# How to get the default value of mongoose using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose in nodejs.
So I defined a schema as below.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
     type: String,
     default: 'kim'
})
```

When I use 'findOne', it gives 'name value' as default, even though, there is no field in its' document.
But when I use '$project of aggregate', there is no name field, when there is no value of name.
How can I get default value using aggregate?
I am using 'mongo 3.6' and 'documentDB of AWS'.
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose applies defaults clientside, aggregation runs serverside and it knows nothing about Mongoose schemas or even nodejs.

If you want to assign default values to the missing fields you need to amend your pipeline by prepending your $project with an extra stage to apply default values explicitly using [$mergeObjects operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            "name": "kim"
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: {...} }
])
```

You will be responsible to maintain it to remain in sync with the schema if defaults change at some point.